# powershell not expanding variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script which installs a load of firewall policies.

I have a file firewalls.txt which has "firewall"  "policy" on a single line. I then put that into a variable and try to call it using the "fwm load" command which is an external firewall application binary but the $fwPolstring is not being expanded within the command

```
    $fwPol = Get-Content firewalls.txt
    $fwPolString = $fwPol
    fwm load "$fwPolString" 2>&1 > InstallLog.txt
```

I get error in InstallLog.txt

```
fwm :  Missing targets
At C:\fw_estate_install.ps1:3 char:1
+ fwm load "$fwPolString" 2>&1 > InstallLog.txt
```

Comment: Just because the *error record* states the command as defined at the call site exactly, it doesn't mean that it wasn't actually expanded

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - If I replace the last line with $fwPolString it returns the firewall and policy name and if I only have "fwm load $fwPolstring" Then I would expect it to work.

Comment: As the error message says, you're missing targets.`fwm load [filter] targets` requires targets; you've only specified a filter. If you're trying to stuff both filter and targets into the file too as one "line", that won't work, since PowerShell will pass the entire contents of the file as the first argument.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you.

        `$fwPol = (Get-Content C:\firewalls.txt) -split ' '

        $fwPolString = $fwPol

        fwm load $fwPol[0]  $fwPol[1]`